# Send log messages to PHP's builtin web server

Tags: php, logging, slim

In my Slim framework application I would like to be able to send log message to the console where I run the PHP builtin web server:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -c /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini-development).
```

I am using the monolog logger:

```
// index.php
$app->container->singleton('log', function () {
  $log = new \Monolog\Logger('myapp');
  $log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('../logs/app.log', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));
  return $log;
});
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use error_log with a `message_type` set to 4 and it will output to the SAPI logging handler:

```
error_log('testing', 4);
```

It will output in this style:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000 test.php
PHP 5.4.20 Development Server started at Wed Jan 22 21:09:35 2014
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /home/David
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Wed Jan 22 21:09:52 2014] testing
```

Monolog also supports this message type using the `ErrorLogHandler` class. Example:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\ErrorLogHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new ErrorLogHandler(ErrorLogHandler::SAPI, Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
$log->addWarning('Foo');
$log->addError('Bar');
```

And the logged output for this:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000 test.php
PHP 5.4.20 Development Server started at Wed Jan 22 21:18:02 2014
Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /home/David/testing
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Wed Jan 22 21:18:06 2014] [2014-01-22 21:18:06] name.WARNING: Foo [] []

[Wed Jan 22 21:18:06 2014] [2014-01-22 21:18:06] name.ERROR: Bar [] []
```

Not quite sure why the monolog version includes the timestamp twice, however.

You can conditionally set which logger to use by checking the `php_sapi_name()` function:

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli-server') {
    /* configure monolog with the ErrorLogHandler */
} else {
    /* configure monolog with the StreamHandler */
}
```

Comment: Upvote for Monolog.  FWIW, Slim Skeleton includes Monolog by default: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Skeleton